# How to solve $y^3=x(x+1)$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm

How to solve $y^3=x(x+1)$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers ? 
Can you help me ?

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean “solve”?

Comment: With a little effort you should be able to find one or two integer solutions, whose inclusion would improve the Question to asking if one can prove them to be the *only* solutions.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: notice that $gcd(x,x+1)=1$ and thus $x=a^3$ and $x+1=b^3$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If two numbers $u$, $v$ are coprime and $uv$ is a $r$-th perfect power, then both $u$ and $v$ are $r$-th perfect powers.